# Package does not exist?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package

My directory structure is:

- `ABC/src/com/example/model/a.java`
- `ABC/src/com/example/web/b.java`

Code for `a.java`:

```
package com.example.model;

public class a {
    // ...
}
```

Code for `b.java`:

```
package com.example.web;

import com.example.model.*;

public class b {
    // ...
}
```

I have already set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to Tomcat's `servlet-api.jar`, so I don't need to include it in the `javac` command.

Now `a.java` compiles fine but when I compile `b.java` it says "package com.example.model does not exist".

How is this caused and how can I solve it? I am using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: why would you not use some IDE  ?

Comment: whats the compile command you are using

Comment: @JigarJoshi   I do use eclipse...and everything works fine there..but just out of curiosity i tried the above and it didn't work!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the output directory (ABC/classes or similar) to the javac classpath so that javac can find the classes.

**Edit:**

Actually, the preferred way is to add the -sourcepath option, as pointed out by AlexR.

That way, the compiler will use the current source of your code instead of the class files from the last time you compiled.

Comment: It may be even better to add the sourcepath as suggested by AlexR. That way the compiler will be able to find classes that haven't been compiled yet.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forget to add `-sourcepath` option. Your compiler does not know where your source is, so it cannot find the a.class previously compiled. If you add this option you even could compile b.java only and a.java will be compiled automatically.

BTW according to java naming convention classes names start with capital letter

Answer (score 0):

Add ABC/src to you classpath and try